# Are accelerations of bodies connected by a rope equal along it?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

If I take a system such that an object of it is hung by a rope running over a pulley and the other being place at some distance on the ground such that the angle between the line passing along the the rope and the object hanging makes an angle theta with the line passing along the rope and the object on the ground. Then if I write relation between velocities and differentiate wrt time I dont get acc. along the rope equal

Comment: Can you draw a diagram please?

Comment: It's semantics of the problem.  If it's an arbitrarily strong and rigid rope, then yes... the velocities will all have to be the same along it, and thus also the acceleration.

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix Note that the OP says that object is on the ground.  I can't say that I understand the setup.   A diagram would help a lot.

Comment: Is the object sliding on the ground?   Please provide a diagram and clarify the statement of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the rope doesn't stretch, only the magnitude of the acceleration will be the same. Acceleration is a vector, and because the pulley applies a force on the rope, the objects will accelerate in different directions and the accelerations are different.

Comment: More specifically:  the components of the acceleration along the direction of the rope are equal.  In this case it's not clear that the motion of the object is in the direction of the rope.   The object is on the ground.   It may be sliding along the ground.